# Simultaneously planning for both PR2 arms using chomp or ompl planer

Tags: robotic-arm, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to simultaneously use for both PR2 arms one of the two planners: chomp planner or ompl planner?

I tried to simultaneously move both PR2 arms using chomp planer. Some times it returns an IK solution for each arm but most often the node "chomp_planner_longrange" crashes or in the best case it reports that no IK solution was found.

Best regards,
Gheorghe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28187/simultaneously-planning-for-both-pr2-arms-using-chomp-or-ompl-planer/) by [Gheorghe](https://answers.ros.org/users/1836/gheorghe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short is no, not with a single CHOMP node and a single copy of other planner subsystems.  It should be possible to do with two CHOMP nodes and two copies of other planner subsystems, however, if that's the route you decide to go.  It should be noted that even in this case the result will be potentially in collision, as neither planner will account for the fact that the other arm is moving.  The right way to do this is to plan for both arms simultaneously, though this may require changing some code.

If you decide to go with two parallel planning subsystems, I'd suggest making a right arm subsystem and a left arm subsystem.  In each namespace put an environment server node, the relevant ik node for the arm, a chomp or ompl planner node, and the relevant copy of move arm.  You should then be able to call different versions of move arm simultaneously.

We are currently working on fully supporting simultaneous planning for both arms, but that won't be ready for release for a little while.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-02-22**:
Could you elaborate a bit on your plans or point to me existing information? E.g. are you planning to work with kinematic tree structures instead of chains?